# Laptop won't power-off, suspend, or hibernate

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, hibernate

HP ProBook 640 G2 running Xubuntu 22.04.3LTS. Had to replace keyboard because several keys stopped working. New keyboard works fine, but now I can't power-off, suspend or hibernate. Any of those options results in immediate hard reboot, as does running "sudo pm-suspend" or "sudo pm-hibernate." Everything else seems ok. Running "halt" from a root shell shuts down properly, but leaves the fan running. Holding the power button down stops the fan and leaves the system powered down. That's the only way I can now power down the computer.

Any ideas on how to get "suspend" and "shutdown" working properly again?